# File download status show specific cell in DataGrid wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

currently i am facing the problem of showing download status (number only) in the row in DataGrid. i am using WPF PRISM MVVM. I start download the document files when the application start. I am using Backgroundworker to keep running the downloading thread. here is the backgroundworker class.

```
 public class BackGroundThread
{
    public BackgroundWorker bgWrk;       

    public BackGroundThread()
    {
        bgWrk = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWrk.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bgWrk.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        bgWrk.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bgWrk.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    public void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) { 

    }

    public void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e){

    }

    public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            int i = 1;
            while (!Overall.stopStatus)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Overall.PercentageDwnd = i;                   
                Overall.caseRefId = "01894-2011";

                if (i%2 == 0)
                {
                    Overall.caseRefId = "01894-2011";
                }
                else
                {
                    Overall.caseRefId = "00932-$$$$";
                }

                if (i == int.MaxValue)
                    i = 0;

                i = i + 1;
            }
    }
}
```

In Backgroundworker's DoWork function, Overall.PercentageDwnd and Overall.caseRefId are keep updating the value (as an example i just pass with sample integer value to Overall.PercentageDwnd).

I can call Overall.PercentageDwnd value in all ViewModel using the following method.

```
public class TestViewModel:BindableBase
{
    public BackgroundWorker subBGW;

    private String _UpdatePer;
    public String UpdatePercentage
    {
        get { return _UpdatePer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _UpdatePer, value); }
    }

    private string _caseId;
    public string CaseID
    {
        get { return _caseId; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _caseId, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> _ViewAKA = new ObservableCollection<tblTransaction>();
    public ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> ViewAKA
    {
        get { return _ViewAKA; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _ViewAKA, value); }
    }            

    public TestViewModel(tblTransaction model)
    {           
        Overall.PercentageDwndChanged += Overall_PercentageDwndChanged;
        Overall.caseRefIdChanged += Overall_CaseRefIdChanged;
    }

    private void Overall_PercentageDwndChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdatePercentage = Overall.PercentageDwnd.ToString();
    }

    private void Overall_CaseRefIdChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CaseID = Overall.caseRefId;
    }

}
```

This is how i bind in view

```
 <Label Content="{Binding UpdatePercentage,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Red" Foreground="White" Margin="130,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Height="39">
```

I can get the data in label box and it is keep increasing. Then my problem start. Actually I want to show this percentage value in DataGrid. 
 I can get which caseRefId is downloading and what is the percentage of downloading by using Overall.PercentageDwnd and Overall.caseRefId.

I got DataGrid view and populated with data. in grid view, there are few columns (caseRefId,caseName,Date,DownloadPercentage). i want to find caseRefId in Datagrid and update percentage value of downloading (Realtime) in DownloadPercentage column.

[image]

How should i do it? totally newbie in WPF PRISM MVVM.

my DataGrid Template

```
 <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,62,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewAKA}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="257" Width="512">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="caseRefNo" Binding="{Binding caseRefNo}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="subjMatr" Binding="{Binding subjMatr}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Download %" Binding="{Binding incValue}" />  
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Label">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label Content="{Binding incValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Red" Foreground="White" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding longTime}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

my TestViewModel

```
public class TestViewModel:BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRepo _Rp;
    public BackgroundWorker subBGW;

    private String _UpdatePer;
    public String UpdatePercentage
    {
        get { return _UpdatePer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _UpdatePer, value); }
    }

    private int _SolidMachine;
    public int SolidMachine
    {
        get { return _SolidMachine; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SolidMachine, value); }
    }

    private string _caseId;
    public string CaseID
    {
        get { return _caseId; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _caseId, value); }
    }

    private tblTransaction model;               

    public TestViewModel(tblTransaction model)
    {           
        Overall.PercentageDwndChanged += Overall_PercentageDwndChanged;
        Overall.caseRefIdChanged += Overall_CaseRefIdChanged;

        _Rp = new Repo();

        List<tblTransaction> lstTransVal = _Rp.getAllTransaction();
        ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> tempObss = new ObservableCollection<tblTransaction>();

        foreach (tblTransaction tbl in lstTransVal)
        {
            if (CaseID == tbl.caseRefNo)
            {
                tbl.incValue = int.Parse(UpdatePercentage);

                tempObss.Add(tbl);
            }
        }
        ViewAKA = tempObss;
    }

    private void Overall_PercentageDwndChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdatePercentage = Overall.PercentageDwnd.ToString();
    }

    private void Overall_CaseRefIdChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CaseID = Overall.caseRefId;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> _ViewAKA = new ObservableCollection<tblTransaction>();
    public ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> ViewAKA
    {
        get { return _ViewAKA; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _ViewAKA, value); }
    }        
}
```

here is code for tblTransaction

```
    namespace EmployeeManager.Model
{
    public class tblTransaction
    {
        public string caseRefNo { get;set;}
        public string subjMatr { get; set; }
        public int incValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? longTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add this Label as datagrid column  in your DataGrid

Comment: i tried already. cannot reflect. i still need to find in caseRefId in DataGrid and update percentage.

Comment: can you paste your datagrid xaml.?

Comment: Hi Kyle already paste my code

Comment: Are you able to show data in DataGrid exactly like in Image.

Comment: 1. Please provide code for tblTransaction. 2. Why you are using ObservableCollection<tblTransaction> tempObss = new ObservableCollection<tblTransaction>(); You can use _ViewAKA which is private data member instead of tempObss straightaway.

Comment: i already uploaded. "Are you able to show data in DataGrid exactly like in Image" -- By right suppose to sir.